# XNA Texturing issue

Tags: c#, xna

Ok, I've been trying a lot of new things lately, and I've had a few stopping points. I decided to leave 3d because I figured I just didn't and couldn't understand the coding involved. I'm pretty good at math though, so I figured I would give it another shot.

I'm trying to learn 3d XNA in c#, I've recently worked out 2d and wish to move on. My problem is that with (in my opinion) the most basic of 3d shapes, a cube, I run into problems. After successfully exporting my cube from blender (after the 7th try **>_>**) and importing it into XNA, I can't get a texture to correctly show on the cube, so I downloaded a cube model from a sample source code file, and attempted to use that, and it's default texture, and I still have problems.

Basically, the code to draw the cube is:

```cs
foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
{
    GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullClockwise;
    foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
    {
        effect.TextureEnabled = true;
        //effect.Texture = texture;
        effect.World = world;
        effect.View = view;
        effect.Projection = projection;
        effect.LightingEnabled = false;
    }
    mesh.Draw();
}
```

The `RenderState` and `LightingEnabled` are new, attempting to fix it myself, when I use my own texture, the texture looks like it's being stretched, and isn't showing the entire image on the cube, but all faces look the same, so it's not wrapping it.

Also, to see all the faces I rotate the cube like:

```cs
position -= new Vector3(0, 0.00f, 0.0100f);
angley += 0.01f;
anglez += 0.01f;

world = Matrix.CreateScale(1.5f) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(anglez) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(angley) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(position);
```

The z change is so I could test another theory.

The default texture is a sandish texture, I'm not sure if it's stretching, because it's almost a solid color. But the box itself seems to be oddly represented (it looks as though I can see through the near faces, and I'm looking at the backs of the opposing ones)

I'm hoping someone can give me a hand, it just seems like it should be much simpler then it seems to be, to draw a simple textured cube, and most of the tutorials online are from older versions of XNA, so the code doesn't match up, and I get lost when trying to replace it with current code. (On tutorials that create a cube in code, rather then a model.)

Anyways, thanks for any answers.

**EDIT 1:**
Drawing this cube with `CreateOrthographic` makes it look correct (the first one uses perspective) but still no texture love :(

**EDIT 2:**
When I use my cube it's stretched, when I use the one from the source, it's a solid color.

**EDIT 3:**
I probably would have gotten an answer sooner had I mentioned I was displaying FPS using a font/`spritebatch`. When I was working out why it wouldn't work, and comparing it to a sample that DID work, I found it, Now, does anyone know how to make that work?

Comment: Continue to use a perspective camera. Orthographic and perspective views are very different. Perspective view is similar to the way the human eye sees the world (many rays of light converging to a small retina), and orthographic view is the way you might see the world if you had a very, very large eye, (e.g if you had a 3 ft wide retina, used to view a 3ft wide object).

Comment: I know, but at the moment I'm just trying to get anything to work correctly, when the application is done i want it to use perspective.

Comment: This time, when i started the app, i saw the texture on the cube for a moment, before it disappeared again. Im hoping that means something?

Comment: I suggest getting a book, or two. 3D rendering is an enormously complex subject. It's not possible to hack your way to an understanding. You have to take the time to learn the principles before you can even begin to write code. Although XNA simplifies the process, it can't simplify the need to first comprehend the technology.

Comment: Hmm, I get the math, and i can place objects in a 3d space and manupulate placement all day long, when im working with theoretical objects, but its the mesh's and textures that get me. Hell i even understand matrices and how to use them >_>, but i cant display meshes with textures on the screen :P, ill give it a little while, in trying to figure out how to do it, then call it quits i guess.

Comment: Also, I cant learn from books :( I can read them, and i can do what they tell me to do, but for some reason, I cant retain what i read from books. Even though i love to read >.<

Comment: You should try to get a known-good mesh and a known-good texture to work, particularly if you have some known-good code to reference. Then you will know if it is your model or your code that is the problem. Try [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197293(v=xnagamestudio.31).aspx) to begin with.

Comment: The same mesh (with its default texture) worked when i replaced the mesh in that tutorial with it, im going to compare it to my code now...

Comment: Oh, (insert explicit sayings here), I didnt think it was relevant, but i had the FPS shown on the screen, using Spritebatch, disabling that made the texture work, i plan on using the text in the future, anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To myself, and anyone else encountering this problem >.<

Are you using:

```
SpriteBatch.begin()
```

to do anything in your code? If so, this is screwing up with the way your program renders in 3d, check out this link (for pre XNA 4.0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2006/11/13/spritebatch-and-renderstates.aspx

And this link if you using XNA 4.0:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/18/spritebatch-and-renderstates-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx

The line in particular that fixed this issue was:

```
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearWrap;
```

Adding that before the foreach loop fixed this problem for me, but you may need to try the other lines in that article

To anyone else reading this, Good luck with your XNA dreams :D